# How to format multiselect form data in JSON

Tags: html, json, angular, angular2-template

I have a template driven form which has multiselect field called assets.
I am using semantic UI.

```html
<div ngModelGroup="assets">
        <div class="field">
          <label for="resourceName">Assets</label>
          <div class="form-control">
            <select ngModel name="resourceName" multiple="" #resourceName="ngModel" id="multi-select" class="ui dropdown" required>
              
          <option *ngFor = "let x of resources" value ="{{x.resourceName}}" >{{ x.resourceName }}</option> 
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

the json I am getting from the dropdown is in the format:
`"assets":{"resourceName":["laptop","keyboard"]}`

but I want it in this format:
`"assets":[{"resourceName":"laptop"},{"resourceName":"keyboard"}]`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` transformation over array to get desired output.

```
this.resources = this.assets.resourceName.map(i => { resourceName: i})
```

Comment: I am new to angular2, please tell the exact method to achieve this. The above method is giving error as `resourceName unused label`.

Comment: @AshishRaj above code supposed to be placed right after your get `assets` filled..